# Filter array of arrays by selectively unsetting values

Tags: php, arrays, string

OK, so I have : an array(a) of arrays(b) of arrays(c).

I'm trying to iterate through the array and **unset** (or to be precise **delete**) all arrays at level 'c', with less than 3 items.

How would you go about it?

I've tried every possible use of `unset` but I still can't the result I need.

```
foreach ($data as $a=>&$data_section)
{
    foreach ((array)$data_section as $b=>$pattern)
    {
        if (count((array)$pattern)<3) { unset($data_section[$b]); }
    }
}
```

This one gives an error :

> Fatal error: Cannot unset string offsets

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

php 5.3+ syntax

```
$data = array_filter($data, function($a){ return count($a) >2; });
```

pre php 5.3

```
function countGreaterThanTwo($a){ return count($a) >2; };
$data = array_filter($data, "countGreaterThanTwo");
```

So in your above example you would do

```
foreach ($data as $a=>&$data_section)
{
    foreach ($data_section as $b=>&$pattern)
    {
        $pattern = array_filter($pattern, function($a){ return count($a) >2; });
    }
}
```

Comment: And what about the nesting? I've also thought about using `array_filter`, but I'm a bit confused as to how to apply it regarding the sub-sub-array (and still avoid `foreach`s)...

Comment: You would have to walk all of the values at level "c" with for each ... this would just trim off the branches that didn't meet. The critera. so you would have to `foreach($data as &$a){foreach($a as &$b){ /* array_filter $b */ }}}` to trim level c

Comment: It might also be helpful to look at [RecursiveArrayIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) for this.